# Node.js server process is already running, can't call endpoints

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, babeljs, nodemon, dotenv

Starting up a pretty basic node.js implementation, I was having issues where it would say the port is already being used, even when it wasn't. I was also having issues where I was no longer able to hit my endpoints, and on save nodemon would error out saying port was being used.

The problem was with .dotenv, and my declaration of the port variable.

I left a semicolon after the port number, which caused these errors. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: could you include the code in question please?

Comment: updated the code, unfortunately I think it might be a mac issue, since I had everything working earlier and now it seems to be creating a file and not working at all... Trying a hard restart, you never know...

Comment: Mac and nodemon especially with typescript causes this EADDRINUSE error a lot.
Run your start command and let it give error. Just go inside any of your js/ts file that triggers nodemon, try to make a change like a simple comment then save. It should trigger and let you to get out of this error. I just do this when i face that error.

Answer (score 0):

Now I feel a bit silly, I defined the port variable with a semicolon....
PORT=3000 works fine
PORT=3000; doesn't work, causes the issues I've been having...